# overlapping tiles in staggered tmx are not visible in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tmx

I used tiled to make a TMX in staggered type.
but when i run my code using this TMX the output in simulator is, overlapping tiles are not visible.

PLEASE HELP ME
code i used in cocos2d is

```
    CCTMXTiledMap *_tileMap =  [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"test.tmx"];
    _tileMap.scale = 1;
    [self addChild:_tileMap z:2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCTMXTiledMap currently does not support staggered isometric tilemaps, only the regular isometric maps.

Comment: but the isometric maps that i create are not visible, only the blank black screen is visible. I've used the same above code for isometric maps too.

Comment: like i said, **staggered** isometric maps (rectangular shaped) are not supported, only **regular** isometric maps are (diamond shaped)

Comment: but when i use diamond shaped **true** isometric maps even then the maps are not visible.

Comment: How big is your map? Cocos2d tilemaps don't draw more than 16,384 tiles. Ie map size 64x64 tiles with 4 layers and all tiles on all layers set and you've reached the maximum. Or one layer with 128x128 tiles.

Comment: Map is small its not that big, I think the problem is with z order or the map position. Please tell me how to set these values so that map will be visible.

Comment: maybe the map position is 0,0 and all you see is the lower-left triangular area of the diamond shape that's empty because there aren't any tiles there due to the map's shape. Try moving the map position to -400,-400 or more to move it into view